# With Sound Arrays, how do I play random unique sounds?

Tags: java, audio, random

So far, this code sounds out the words "This is a test" in random order, but the words can repeat more than once. myWordArray is a static Sound array set up in the program that reads splice points from the specific sound.

```
public void playRandomOrder(int totalWords, int pause) throws InterruptedException {
    Random random = new Random(); // Random number generator for array shuffle
    for (int i =0; i< numWords; i++) {
        int randomPosition = random.nextInt(totalWords); // how many words to sound out (4)
        Sound temp = myWordArray[i];
        myWordArray[i] = myWordArray[randomPosition];
        myWordArray[randomPosition] = temp;
        myWordArray[i].blockingPlay();
        Thread.sleep(pause); // 320 m.seconds, as listed in main method parameter
}
}
```

I want it to be so that the words can play randomly, but without a single word repeating. For example "This a test is" instead of "This is is test" Here is what I have so far for the unique random words...

```
public void playRandomUnique(int pause) throws InterruptedException {
    final Random random = new Random();
    List<Sound> list = Arrays.asList(myWordArray);
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Sound>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Sound o1, Sound o2){
            return random.nextInt() % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
        }
    });
    list.toArray(myWordArray);
    for (Sound sound: myWordArray)
        sound.blockingPlay();
        Thread.sleep(pause);

}
```

This however, results in "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!" and no sound plays out when I run it in main.

Comment: Have you tried shuffling your list? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)

Comment: Your Comparator will not work.  The `compare` method must behave consistently.  The “general contract” is that compare(a,b) must return a sign opposite that returned by compare(b,a).  Also, compare(a,a) must return zero.  All that said, you are much better off using Collections.shuffle, as Knossos suggested.

Comment: How would I go about implementing collections.shuffle in my current code? I tried doing it before but to no avail.

Comment: Can anyone offer some more assistance? I've been dealing with this for the past 2 days and I have no clue how to solve it with Sound Arrays...